# publishing apps in Play Store android

Tags: android

I have completed my apps development and about to publish it in Play Store , before that I have a small doubt

I have a "Rate in play store" button which would take the user to the play store for rating my app , but how could I get my app URL in the Play Store , before publishing it , so that I can put the URL in the " onRate() " method

Or

Is there is any other way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link to your app in the Play Store using your package name (defined in your manifest). The URI is constructed like this:

From an App:

```
market://details?id=<package_name>
```

From a Website:

```
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>
```

See [Linking to Your Products](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html) for more information.